# How to increase supplyCap on aave v3

Tags: solidity, aave

I am working with aave-v3 on testnet deployed from the @aave-v3-deply deployment repo. I am unable to increase the `supplyCap` on the pool via the `poolConfigurator`.I have all the permission on the `aclManager`. I get error 69 (Invalid supply cap) the I call PoolConfigurator.setSupplyCap()

```
    function setSupplyCap(
        address asset,
        uint256 newSupplyCap
    ) external override onlyRiskOrPoolAdmins {
        DataTypes.ReserveConfigurationMap memory currentConfig = _pool
            .getConfiguration(asset);
        uint256 oldSupplyCap = currentConfig.getSupplyCap();
        currentConfig.setSupplyCap(newSupplyCap);
        _pool.setConfiguration(asset, currentConfig);
        emit SupplyCapChanged(asset, oldSupplyCap, newSupplyCap);
    }
```

I tried checking the function on the pool configurator but could not trace where

```
        **DataTypes.ReserveConfigurationMap** memory currentConfig = _pool
        .getConfiguration(asset);
   

currentConfig.**setSupplyCap**(newSupplyCap);
```

the **setSupplyCap** is implemented for the **DataTypes.ReserveConfigurationMap** struct.

Comment: Can you put your entire smart contract code?

Comment: I am working with a fork of aave-v3. nothing has been changed on the contract.